# Extracting an RDD column into a new RDD

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have an rdd with multiple columns and want to extract a column called "age". I tried:

```
rddAge = df.rdd.map(lambda row: Row(age=row.age))
```

The code returns no errors. But when I simply try to do a rddAge.count(), I get a very long traceback with:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 29.0 failed 10 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.9 in stage 29.0 (TID 365, yp-spark-dal09-env5-0048): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last): ...
```

Am I doing it wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I tried your code and doing fine...
Can you post what do you do with df?

Comment: You don't dump the important components of the stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you importing Row? Importing Row works fine for me

```
from pyspark.sql import Row

rddAge = df.rdd.map(lambda row: Row(age=row.rddAge))
rddAge.count()
```

Answer (score 0):

In `Spark 2`, you can directly `select` the column on top of dataframe, the corresponding code snippet in `scala` is:

```
val ageDF = df.select("age")
ageDF.printSchema()
```

output:

```
root
 |-- age: long (nullable = true)
```

Hope this helps...